# How can I change cgroup memory limits in Redhat 9 or Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: cgroups

I have a docker container which requires 16GB RAM in order to run, plus some extra from some processes it starts. The memory consumption on the machine seems to peak at 60-70% from total memory (64GB). However, it seems that `cgroup` is killing the process at this point:

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 2552559 (wi) total-vm:75308048kB, anon-rss:16499856kB, file-rss:2192kB,shmem-rss:83876kB, UID:0 pgtables:36892kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I haven't done any configuration of `cgroups`, so I have no idea where it takes the default values from and how can I modify them. Any idea how can I increase these memory limits or scrap them all together?

Tried looking in various sources, but I can't find a memory limit set anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The irresponsible answer is as per https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ to set `--oom-kill-disable` on the container.

The responsible answer is to dig in and figure out why your docker consumes more memory than supposedly required, and either adjust the docker file to reflect actual requirement, or fix the apps running inside the docker instance to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the answer, this machine exist solely to run this docker container, and even at peak, I haven't seen it above 70% of the memory of the machine. I think this is a reasonable number and the container should not be killed, so I'm guessing the issue lies with the limits of cgroup(or something else).

Comment: Just set a new memory limit in  docker. Docker is a cgroup consumer, and knows how to "talk" to cgroup already. You can either set memory limit at bringup with `docker run --memory="[memory_limit]"` or update during runtime with `docker update --memory` or with whatever you use to deploy the container. Just change the 16GB configuration to the new desired value...